# What is the good option to trace/log the custom Roslyn analyzer implementation?

Tags: logging, roslyn, trace, roslyn-code-analysis

We are getting intermittent crashes and additional file load issues from build machine.
Unfortunately this happens only in build machine where we run automated scripts.
This we are unable to trace as we don't have tracing or logging mechanism in place.
What is the good option to log/trace analyzers for troubleshooting such scenarios. It would be great if we could get additional tracing/logs in the msbuild output.

Currently we only have findings reported gets printed to msbuild log.

Comment: This isn't specific to Roslyn--you need to instrument your code using a general-purpose logging framework. I'm partial to [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging), but any framework will do.